# preview of text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I have the following html

`<img src="a.jpg" /><p> This is some random text and just to test this example. This is some random text and just to test this example. This is some random text and just to test this example<p>
 <br><p>This is some random text and just to test this example This is some random text and just to test this example</p>
<img src="a.jpg" />
 <br><p>This is some random text and just to test this example This is some random text and just to test this example</p>`

My question is that if i have to give a preview of the text only using jquery suppose i have this in a variable named html how to display only few parts of the text ignoring the images

```
       <div id="preview"></div>
       $("#preview").val("//display only text in the variable named html")
```

Comment: hi rajeev .. good name you have :-) your question not so clear. i think you are wanted to put value in another div by getting it from html div. am i right ?  then use this $("#preview").html("//display only text in the variable named html")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) images from the html:

```
var someHtml = '....';
$('#preview').html($(someHtml).filter(':not("img")'));
```

Comment: @Rajeev, you have many paragraphs here. Which one do you want to limit to 200 characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#preview').html(textWithTags.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").substr(0, 200));
```

Note: use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `.val()` for DIV.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Here `.content` is class of wrapper of whole html you post
```

***CODE:***

```
$('.preview').click(function(){ // Here `.preview` is the `class` of submit button
    html = $('.content').contents(':not(img)');
    $('#preview').html(html)
});
```

**OR**

```
$('#preview').html($(yourhtml).not('img'));
```

**OR**

```
html = $('.content').html();
yourhtml = $(html).contents(":not('img')").text().substr(0, 200).concat('...'); // here  I add `concat('...')` just for continuity. you may remove it,
$('#preview').html(yourhtml);
```

Comment: here i wrap your html with a `div` having class `content`

Comment: @Rajeev first two solution will set whole html to `#preview` but last solution will set `text` to `#preview`.